# Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 through ssh in python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, dbus

I connect to my remote computer with :

```
    self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(hostname=ip_address, username=self.user, password=self.password, look_for_keys=False)
```

When I send commands :

```
    chan = self.client.get_transport().open_session(timeout=timeout)
    chan.request_x11()
    chan.settimeout(timeout)
    chan.exec_command(command)
    stdin = chan.makefile('wb', -1)
    stdout = chan.makefile('r', -1)
    stderr = chan.makefile_stderr('r', -1)
    return stdin, stdout, stderr
```

If I do not use this line :

```
chan.request_x11()
```

I tried using :

```
self.client.exec_command(command)
```

but same error

I get the error message from the title. When I use the line I get a timeout connection when trying to read from stdout. I tried setting

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

Did nothing. I'm trying to send dbus commands through ssh. When I connect in ssh manually through the terminal I can use the -X or not use it and I can use my dbus calls it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

To use Dbus from Shell without X11/Display.
Dbus need to know DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS.
so either you export this or export DISPLAY...

1) Export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS method.

First Launch server.
eval 'dbus-launch --auto-syntax ' ./server

from the server environ (/proc/pid-server/environ)
you can get DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS. 
Export that value in your shell where you are launching client program,
launch client
./client ...
It should work without problem.